# Call function in instance of class from a sub-form in C#

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is really simple, but I just can't find the right phrase to google.

I have an application that is meant to be a tray application.

The Main() function initializes an instance of a class `CustomApplicationContext`:

```
 private static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new CustomApplicationContext());
}
```

Within this class, I have a function:

```
public void DoRestart()
{

  if (_DoRestartDialog == null)
  {
    using (_DoRestartDialog = new RestartDialog())
      _DoRestartDialog.ShowDialog();
      _DoRestartDialog = null;
  }
  else
    _DoRestartDialog.Activate();
}
```

I also have a function in this class that opens a form:

```
protected override void OnTrayIconDoubleClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
            if (_InfoDialog == null)
            {
                using (_InfoDialog = new InfoDialog())
                    _InfoDialog.ShowDialog();
                _InfoDialog = null;
            }
            else
                _InfoDialog.Activate();
           
  }

  base.OnTrayIconDoubleClick(e);
}
```

Within the form is a button. When the button is clicked I want to call the DoRestart function in the primary class. How do I reference this function? I can't seem to get access to it from the form.

Comment: You can pass a reference to `this` in a parameterized constructor of your InfoDialog form.

Comment: Pass an instance of the class to the Form preferably through the constructor

Comment: Why do you do this: `_DoRestartDialog = null`?

Comment: @Flydog57 this is code I downloaded. So, your guess is probably as good as mine. But, my understanding is that this is a mechanism to prevent multiple dialog boxes being opened from the tray icon,  after the dialog box closes it needs to set it to null so that the if statement will execute the code next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing your instance directly to `Run()`, store it at class level first:

```
public static CustomApplicationContext App;

private static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    App = new CustomApplicationContext();
    Application.Run(App);
}
```

Now you can access it with:

```
Program.App.DoRestart();
```

Comment: How do I account for creating a new instance. I get the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` - Thanks

Comment: Update your code to show what you've done and we can troubleshoot.

Comment: I updated to exactly what you show here. It does allow me to reference Program.App.DoRestart() in my form. But it's complaining at "Application.Run(App)" - Null object

Comment: Then you missed the line directly above it: `App = new CustomApplicationContext();`

Comment: That did the trick. I definitely missed that. Fyi, you're missing a semi-colon at the end of that line. Thank you again.